# Don't allow browser to scale text

Tags: html, css

In some smartphones browsers is set ( by default ) font zoom - like for example 130%. How can i dont allow browser to resize font?

Sorry for my english

Comment: hmmmm waiting fro its answer :)

Comment: Whats wrong if it's resized?

Comment: Forcing people to use unreadable micro-fonts is a terrible idea.

Comment: But my website is responsive and i'm resizing fonts on my own

Comment: @user2075220 You can't override a browser's behaviour.

Comment: _“i'm resizing fonts on my own”_ – still a bad idea. Instead of using the built-in controls/mechanisms for that, that the user knows and is accustomed to, they most likely have to find and maybe even “learn” your individual solution first. And that the user might have a general default zoom set because it meets their requirements (bad eyesight, …) will most likely not be recognized by your solution _automatically_ as well. So you are not only re-inventing the wheel, you are also delivering a wheel that performs less good than the original wheel.

Answer (score 1):

I found this for fonts. I'm not sure it will work on different systems, but you could give it a try:

```
    body {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    }
```

It seems you can also turn auto-scaling off:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```